# Remove uploaded .ipa file from Apple App Store after receiving ITMS-90732 Error

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, ipa, xcrun

I uploaded a zipped version of my iOS app binary .ipa file using the following altool command:

```
xcrun altool --notarize-app --primary-bundle-id <myBundleID> --username <myUsername> --password <myPassword> --file <pathToMyZippedIPAFile>
```

And received a "no errors uploading" response, along with a `RequestUUID`. Unfortunately, this submission doesn't show up anywhere in the App Store as "processing", which is the expected behavior.

In trying this command again, I get the following error:

```
ERROR ITMS-90732: "The software asset has already been uploaded."
```

I ran the `--notarization-info` command to check for any errors with my uploaded binary, and there are some, according to the log file:

```
"issues": [
    {
      "severity": "error",
      "code": null,
      "path": "MyApp.zip",
      "message": "Package MyApp.zip has no signed executables or bundles. No tickets can be generated.",
      "docUrl": null,
      "architecture": null
    }
  ]
```

So now I just want to remove that previously uploaded file, but since I don't see it anywhere in App Store Connect, and I'm unaware of a command to do that from the terminal, I'm not sure how.

How can I remove that previously uploaded binary?

Comment: Try uploading a new version like 1.0.1